# Copy and archive every Gmail attachment to Google Drive

Tags: gmail, google-drive

What is the way do download every attachment within a label? I want every PDF invoice I get to be put in my file system, so I figured I'd need Google Drive.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) which can be used to automate tasks involving GMail, Drive, and other google services.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Send to Google Drive](http://www.labnol.org/internet/send-gmail-to-google-drive/21236/) script. It will auto-save the Gmail attachments to your Drive folder.